# Databricks Spark throws java.io.NotSerializableException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks, aws-databricks

Hi I am trying to run the following code on Databricks which is a 3 node spark cluster
I retrieve the data from kinesis stream into a spark dataframe and transform it to extract the payload json file name

In the below code I am trying to download data from AWS s3 for each json file name
my payload is a string of the form "filename.json"

```
import scala.io.Source
import com.amazonaws.services.s3._
import java.io.InputStream
val ds = interim_df_v1.select("payload").mapPartitions(iterator => {
    val s3Client: AmazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client()
    val res = iterator.flatMap(row=>{
        var bucket = "bucket_name"
        Source.fromInputStream(s3Client.getObject(bucket, row.getString(0)).getObjectContent: InputStream).getLines
    })
    res
  })
```

Tried creating a **Singleton** object to access the s3 client also **mapPartitions** but nothing seems to work, getting the following error

```
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2872)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemorySink.addBatch(memory.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:580)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:835)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client, value: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client@73d83b2c)
    - field (class: line019c6b4503ad49929c23c8abc36c49b4166.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: s3Client, type: interface com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3)
```

Please let me know for any other workarounds

Comment: Can you please try broadcasting the s3client object from driver and pass it to the executors and use that variable inside executor ?